# If clicked on LI, the input radio inside li should checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple LI and in that li I am having input as radio, 
and on clicking on li it will show different data at the right side, the data is showing properly only the problem is- 
What I want is,If I have clicked on Li I want to add "checked" property to input inside that Li.
If I have clicked on another LI , the "checked" property will remove from previous radio box and add it to the respective radio box inside the clicked Li

My html code sample:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>   <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="allRoles" onclick="" class="user-roles">
    <div class="grpRow">
        <span class="radio-placeholder">
            <input type="radio" name="userRole" value="6" id="6" style="display:none"></span>
            <span>Admin</span><br>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Following is my script:

```
$(".list-unstyled li").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                $(".active .radio-placeholder input").attr("checked","CHECKED");
            }
            else{
                $(".active .radio-placeholder input").each(function(){
                    if(!$(this).parents("li").hasClass('active')){
                      $(this).removeAttr("checked","CHECKED");
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Please guide me as soon as possible.

Comment: multiple <li> are having same id...I think that is incorrect way...there can only be one element for a given element...use class attribute instead.

Comment: Element IDs should be unique within the entire document, duplicate Ids are invalid markup. If you wish to do something like that with you lis, use a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".list-unstyled > li").click(function(){
    $(".list-unstyled > li").find('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

pls fix your html, remove multiple uses of same id, nestings and end of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $(".active .radio-placeholder input").prop('checked', true);
```